# Converting "12345678" into "1-234-5678", my code produces nothing

Tags: c++, arrays, string, cout

It's not showing any errors but for some reason my cout's wont show up. Am I missing something? I'm trying to convert a series of numbers to a typical phone number format.

```
int numberCount = 0;
string phoneNumberUnform = "12345678";
for (size_t i = 0; i < phoneNumberUnform.length(); i++)
{
    numberCount++;
}
if (numberCount = 8)
{
    string phoneNumber[10];
    phoneNumber[0] = phoneNumberUnform[0];
    phoneNumber[1] = "-";
    for (int i = 2; i = 5; i++)
    {
        phoneNumber[i] = phoneNumberUnform[i-1];
    }
    phoneNumber[6] = "-";
    for (int i = 7; i = 10; i++)
    {
        phoneNumber[i] = phoneNumberUnform[i-1];
    }   
    cout << phoneNumberUnform;
    cout << phoneNumber;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 2; i = 5; i++)` and `for (int i = 7; i = 10; i++)` are infinite loops. `i = 5` (and `i = 10`) are an assignments, did you want to compare the values? In addition, your initial `if` (`numberCount = 8`) has an assignment instead of comparison.

Comment: Your initial loop is irrelevant. You'd get the same result just using `numberCount = phoneNumberUnform.length()`.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen There's so much **no** in the code, that there is no point in trying to fix it. When I started to write my initial comment, I noticed just one thing. Several edits later, I gave up..

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius True, but still, he might learn from our comments.

Answer (score 7):

Use the std::string's [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) member function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s = "123456789";
    s.insert(1, "-");
    s.insert(5, "-");
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

For the manual approach, resize the original string to accommodate the additional two characters:

```
std::string s = "123456789";
std::string temp = s;
int strlen = temp.length();
s.resize(s.length() + 2);

s[1] = '-';

for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++)
{
    s[i] = temp[i - 1];
}
s[5] = '-';
for (int i = 6; i < strlen + 2; i++)
{
    s[i] = temp[i - 2];
}
```

In the second loop use the `temp[i - 2]` index instead of the `temp[i - 1]` one because by then we have already inserted the two `-` characters into our original string.